# Recover overwritten RAID5 array (XOR)

Tags: debian, raid, lvm, mdadm

As I've mentioned in a recent question ([RAID5 rescue with LVM2 running on it](https://serverfault.com/questions/686384/raid5-rescue-with-lvm2-running-on-it)) I'm rebuilding an RAID5 array.

Now, I think that the initial wrong

```
mdadm --create ...
```

command has started the rebuild.

When I analyze the parity data I can see that starting from sector 200000 the parity data makes sense again.

[image]

Beyond this raid I have a LVM, the initial two lvm partitions are not relevant (containing debian root and swap). But at the end...

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it seems to **non**-match, aborting the resync should not alter your data that fast.

If you are running a large-array (like 1TB disks), the resync normally takes hours, so aborting it should keep your data.

In my case it worked, even if it seems to be mismatching.

Whenever you get your raid running, keep in mind to **backup** your data afterwards and **rebuild** the array then.